# Relationship between three different definitions of solutions for ODE with irregular coefficient

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, hyperbolic-pde

What is the difference between the notions of

- [Regular Lagrangian flow](http://cvgmt.sns.it/media/doc/paper/1612/crippa_bari.pdf)
- [Filippov solution](http://calvino.polito.it/~bacciotti/ijpam.pdf)
- [Caratheodory solution](http://calvino.polito.it/~bacciotti/ijpam.pdf)

of an ODE $\dot \Phi(t,x) = b(t,\Phi(t,x))$, with initial condition $\Phi(0,x) = x$,  where $b$ is a non-smooth (that is, non-Lipschitz) vector field?

In general, are they related in any way? Under which (non-trivial) assumptions are they equivalent? Which is the strongest notion of solutions between these?